# NoSuchElementException or ElementNotInteractableException when attempting to click on a pop-up widget element

Tags: python, html, jquery, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to click on the `ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus` which is a filter option for value `No` nested in a div > unordered list > list > anchor > span structure. The other filter option `Yes` is a part of the unordered list and is provided for additional context to the HTML elements.

```
<div class="available right-column" style="width: 238px;">
    <div class="actions ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
        <input type="text" class="search empty ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <a class="add-all" href="#" >Add all</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="available connected-list" style="height: 172px;">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="No">
            <span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>
            No
            <a class="action" href="#">
                <span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-element ui-draggable" title="Yes">
            <span class="ui-helper-hidden"></span>
            Yes
            <a class="action" href="#">
            <span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following and all permutations possible:

```
# Option 1. Wait for target elem to be visible
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ui-draggable:nth-child(1)')))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus')))

# Option 2. Wait for target elem to be clickable
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.ui-draggable:nth-child(1)')))
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus')))


# Option 3. Various locator types (XPATH, CLASS_NAME, etc..)
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.<locator_types>, <locator>)))
```

I have also discovered an overlay element when this pop-up widget appears that has a high z-index value:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 1728px; height: 1033px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
```

So in effort to hide this overlay to allow for target elem to be visible and interactable, I've tried the following:

```
overlay_element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="cz_transBG"]')
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.zIndex = '0';", overlay_element)
```

This does hide the overlay, but the target elem is still resulting in the errors mentioned in title.

Other considerations I've explored with no avail:

1. iframe switch - target elm is not nested in an iframe
2. jQuery event handlers - mimiced on mouse hovers using `execute_script()` as the  `<ul>` elms seemed to have some event handlers that could've been preventing the target elm from being clicked until an action was taken
3. Nested `find_element()` - drilling down the elms to reach the target elm did not work (anchor elm > span elm.`click()` )
4. A combination of both (3) and (2) above

Additional information worth mentioning:

- The `<li>` elms are draggable
- Both `<ul>` and `<li>` elms have (2) events`click` , `mouseover` and (3) events  `click`, `mousedown`, `remove`  ,respectively. I'm very unfamiliar about this stuff and only aware of its relation to jQuery events.
- Chromedriver is being used